# Autowire spring jpa repository in custom authentication provider

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

since a few hours i try to get the autowire working in my custom authentication provider class for spring security 4.1.3.

I have two maven projects:

1. MyService
2. MyWebGUI

"MyService" is a service to interact with my database. It includes the spring data framework. Thats why i have my entity classes and my respoitory classes.

In "MyWebGUI" i use the spring security framework for a login.
Now i included my "MyService" dependency in my "MyWebGUI" pom.xml.

To get my login working, i created a custom authentication provider in "MyWebGUI" project and autowired my repository class from "MyService" to get the correct user from my database.

The problem is, that i could't start my "MyWebGUI" project, because spring security seems to block autowiring in the custom authentication provider.

Or is it possible, that at startup my "MyService" dependency with the nedded repository is not loaded?

Edit:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired
UserRepository ur;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication arg0) throws AuthenticationException {
    String username = arg0.getName();
    String password = arg0.getCredentials().toString();

    User user = ur.findUserByUsername(username);

    if (user == null || !user.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Username not found.");
    }

    if (!password.equals(user.getPassword())) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong password.");
    }

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, user.getAuthorities());
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

}

Here i get an error, that the interface "UserRepository" could not be found.

Structur of MyService:

MyService

- com.test
- - UserRepository

Structur of MyWebGUI:

MyWebGUI

- com.test
- - CustomAuthenticationProvider

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you post relevant code to help others to give a try?

Comment: I added some code

Comment: What about UserRepository class? Is it annotated? and package of UserRepository  class is included in @componentscan?

Comment: Yes, the "UserRepository" is annotated with "@Repository", because it's a spring data jpa interface. 

And in the "applicationContext.xml" of "MyWebGUI" is the base-package of the component-scan "com.test".

Comment: Ok, i think the problem is, that i try to inject a class from my external "MyService" jar. Now i have to figure out, how to do that.

Comment: When i copy the "MyService" jar into the tomcat lib folder, "MyWebGUI" is working perfect. But else it didn't work. What i have to do that it works without copying the file into the lib folder?

Comment: Ok, now it works perfekt. I don't know why, but i disabled the "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects" option, and noww it works.